# What's the correct way to get to the username using EL? 

Tags: jsp, el

I have a static method that returns a list of a type. In order for me to get a username from type I have to do the following `type.getUser.getUserName`. What's the correct way to get to the username using EL? I tried `type.user.userName`, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${type.user.userName}` is the proper way to go. If it "doesn't work" (how exactly it doesn't?), it may be because the `user` is `null`.

Comment: it's returning blanks, but let me check and see if it's null. That could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The correct EL syntact would be `type.user.userName`. That is without the getters.